# Mutate Element of Range View

Tags: c++, range-v3

I have a 2-dimensional vector of enums `std::vector<std::vector<enum>>`, the enum can have the values `a (0), b (1), c(2)`. I would like to randomly set one of the `a`'s to `c` and thought I'll try out the ranges library.

Currently I have a view of all the `a`s in my 2d vector using this:

`auto g = view::join(vec) | filter([](my_enum x){ return x == my_enum::a; };`

I found `view::sample` that sounds useful to randomly select an element, but didn't know how to use it since I got confused about the size of another range it needs as a parameter? [(view::sample doc)](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/classranges_1_1v3_1_1view_1_1sample__fn.html)

Next step would also be to mutate that randomly selected element. As far as I understood it, `ranges::v3::view` only provides a non-mutable view on elements. So is it at all possible to mutate a selected element?

Comment: I'm confused by `return x : enumname::a;`. In what context is that valid C++? Did you mean `==` instead of `:`?

Comment: Yes, sorry that was a typo. `return x == my_enum::a` for example.